# ElasticSearch AbstractMethodError while making client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to make an elastic search transport client, but getting below error

> Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.sendMessage(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/elasticsearch/common/bytes/BytesReference;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.internalSendMessage(TcpTransport.java:1111)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.sendRequestToChannel(TcpTransport.java:1093)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.executeHandshake(TcpTransport.java:1600)

Here is my code :

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
        .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
        .put("node.name", "node1").build();

TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
```

Is this a dependency issue?

Comment: How do your dependencies look like? If you have a Maven or Gradle project, can you post your dependencies?

Comment: yes, its a dependency issue. In maven dependency i have these dependencies  `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.3</version>
        </dependency>`   Now i have removed the dependency of org.elasticsearch, now it is running fine.

Comment: I had a similar problem but couldn't get rid of the `elasticsearch` dependency (isn't it needed by `transport`)?  My issue was caused by mismatched `elasticsearch` and `transport` versions - setting them to the same version eliminated the problem.

Comment: @sorabhsolanki you should probably add an answer and mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a dependency issue. In maven pom, i have below dependencies

```
<dependency> 
   <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId> 
   <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId> 
   <version>5.6.2</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
   <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
   <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
   <version>5.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I have removed the dependency of org.elasticsearch, and it is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on this.  You can't mix dependency versions.

Turned out I was using `spring-data-elasticsearch` in one project that depended on another project that had the plain `elasticsearch` dependency.  These included differing versions and caused that error.

That was not fun to track down.